# Caching Cookies in Awesomium

Tags: winforms, awesomium

**The Setup:**

I am building an MDI Application. One of the Child Forms I call is a basic web browser using the Awesomium API.

Reference: `BrowserControl.cs`

```
public partial class BrowserControl : UserControl
{
    public BrowserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnControlLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String w3DataPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\HttpAgent";
        if (!Directory.Exists(w3DataPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(w3DataPath);
        }
        var webSession = WebCore.CreateWebSession(w3DataPath, WebPreferences.Default);
        webControl.WebSession = webSession;
    }

    private void OnBackButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webControl.GoBack();
    }

    private void OnFwdButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webControl.GoForward();
    }

    private void OnReloadButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webControl.Reload(true);
    }

    private void OnStopButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webControl.Stop();
    }

    private void OnHomeButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webControl.GoToHome();
    }

    private void OnSearchButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String urlString = String.Format("https://www.google.com/#q={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(this.SearchBox.Text));
        this.webControl.Source = new System.Uri(urlString);

    }

    private void OnLoadingFrame(object sender, Awesomium.Core.LoadingFrameEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BrowserStatus.Text = "Loading " + e.Url;
    }

    private void OnLoadingComplete(object sender, Awesomium.Core.FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BrowserStatus.Text = "Document Ready";
    }

    private void OnLoadingFailure(object sender, Awesomium.Core.LoadingFrameFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BrowserStatus.Text = e.ErrorDescription;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** Functionally the browser works just fine; however, it does not cache any persistent data locally. Note, I have established a valid `DataPath` using the Awesomium `WebSession` object as indicated in the above method `OnControlLoad()`

In terms of the validity of the path I define - I have confirmed it does exist on disk and it even appears the Awesomium WebSession adds a sub-directory called "cache". Unfortunately, none of the cookies I am getting in my web session are being saved locally. In fact - nothing is being cached. Both the HttpAgent directory I define and the cache directory the `WebSession` object defines are empty after deliberately logging into sites I know set cookies.

Any insight or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it helps but try closing Awesomium "correctly": dispose WebControls, WebSession, call `WebCore.Shutdown()`.

Comment: Good Point Alex - I will give that a try!